# Manager Spring MVC @RequestMapping in config file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC framework, we have annotation`@RequestMapping` and something like `@RequestMapping(value = "mycontroller/fulfill/order/{myOrder}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Is there a way I can actually put all of those value (url) into a config file and manage them there?
For example, as you can see this url starts with "mycontroller" (basically all of my controllers start with this variable). If I change this variable in the future, I do not want to change it one by one instead of just changing at one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RequestMapping annotations support ${string​} placeholders against local properties and/or system properties and environment variables.

You need to create a .properties file. Then have this read by a PropertPlaceholderConfigurer which your have wired in spring. The key (value left of the = is what goes in the ${} placeholder in your annotation. See [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) for an example.

Comment: How could I actually add this variable in the config or build.xml? Thanks